# How to recite hallel with fewer than 3 men at seder

Tags: halacha, passover-seder-hagada, hallel, zimun

[Are you supposed to do the responsive parts of Hallel at the Seder?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/401/are-you-supposed-to-do-the-responsive-parts-of-hallel-at-the-seder) indicates that, when three men are at the seder, Hallel is recited responsively.

At the seder, does one recite Hallel responsively with a table of 2 adult men and 1 adult woman?  If so, is it because the woman's chiyuv is the same as the man's in this regard?

If there is one adult man, one adult woman, and young children below bar mitvzah, is Hallel recited responsively?

I checked the mishna berura but it wasn't clear what his opinion was.

Comment: The accepted answer at the question link to provides a source that addresses your question precisely.